# Using Tensorflow for workload distribution

Tags: tensorflow

My code looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 16, num_ckfs = 5
init_variances = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[ num_ckfs, N],name='inital_variances')

init_states = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[num_ckfs, N], name='init_states')

#some more code

predicted_state =  prior_state_expanded + kalman_gain * diff_expanded

error_covariance = sum_cov_cholesky + tf.batch_matmul(kg , kalman_gain, adj_x=True)


projected_output = tf.batch_matmul(predicted_state,input_vectors_extra, adj_y=True)

session = tf.Session()  

# read data from input file

init_var = [10 for i in range(N)]
init_var_ckfs = [init_var for i in range(num_ckfs)]



init_state = [0 for i in range(N)]
init_state_ckfs = [init_state for i in range(num_ckfs)]

for timestep in range(10):

   out= session.run([projected_output, predicted_state, error_covariance], {init_variances:init_var_ckfs,     init_states:init_state_ckfs })
   init_state_ckfs = np.array([i.tolist()[0] for i in out[1]])
   init_var_ckfs = np.array([i.diagonal().tolist() for i in out[2]])
```

This code is for running a Cubature Kalman Filter(CKF) in a batched mode. For example:

```
num_ckfs = 5
```

means that this code will run 5 CKFs in parallel. Now, what I would like to do is to distribute the workload to multiple nodes depending upon the value of num_ckfs. For example, if I pass num_ckfs as an argument to the code, and it is set to 20,000, then I would distribute the workload to 4 nodes running 5000 each.

I would like to do this using the distributed version of Tensorflow. Can someone please give me some hints on how this could be achieved? Ideally, I should have to execute the code on a single node and it should then get distributed to as many nodes as defined in

```
tf.train.ClusterSpec
```

Comment: You can use `with tf.device(device)` block to specify which device (worker) the computation is executed on

Comment: I want the entire graph to run on all the devices.

Comment: if computation is identical, you could replicate `with tf.device` k times (with a helper function)